# Rake task occasionally fails, undefined error

Tags: ruby, rake

I check out a fresh commit in a repo that works for everyone else. I run a rake task, which calls this code and throws an `undefined` error, even though `Gem.source_index` appears to be defined.

```
module Gem
  puts "in module Gem"
  def self.source_index=(index)
    puts "defining the source index"
    @@source_index = index
  end
end

module Rails
  class GemDependency < Gem::Dependency
    attr_accessor :lib, :source, :dep

    def self.add_frozen_gem_path
      puts "Oh hi there"
      puts "the source index is " + Gem.source_index // ERROR HERE
    end
```

The output is

```
in module Gem
Oh hi there
rake aborted!
undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gem.source_index` was deprecated in Ruby 1.9 and removed in Ruby 2.0*.  I suspect you're using Ruby 2.0 now, which would give you that exact error.

Note that you do define a setter for it, but not a getter.

(* Technically it's probably tied to a specific version of Rubygems rather than Ruby.  A 1.9.3 installation with an upgraded rubygems installation would amount to the same thing.)

Comment: This worked! I did `rvm list` and then `rvm use ree-1.8.7-2012.02`